# XCode subproject preprocessor override

Tags: xcode

My project has an external Mapbox-ios-sdk subproject which utilizes FMDB (copied as references in Mapbox-ios-sdk, not a sub-project). I intend to let FMDB link with SpatiaLite instead of stock SQLite. SpatiaLite has a new definition of sqlite3.h which includes some macro to rename C function definitions (such as `#define sqlite3_bind_double SPLite3_bind_double`). I want FMDB stuff to include this version of sqlite3.h. Mapbox-ios-sdk does not include sqlite3.h, I suspect it just uses the framework `libsqlite3.dylib` but I have no idea how that dynamic framework is about.

I am able to make it do so by copying sqlite3.h into Mapbox-ios-sdk and make it include it. However I don't really like to do this as Mapbox-ios-sdk is an external project. What option do I have?